# How can I align Chart title with the bar dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, crossfilter

How can I align Chart title with the bar in highcharts?

The bar length may vary because of the data, so I want my title to end where the bar is ending.

I want to implement something like this:

[image: chart example]

Comment: There are several bars on the fiddle. Do you want to right align the title based on the longest bar?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to provide enough code for people to tell what you are doing. The answer would depend which charting library you are using - I guess highcharts because you used the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a `padding-right: ##px` as you havent provided any code to work with. try applying the method via inspect element and add the code into your css after with the right amount of "px" needed.

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the title you can set `tittle.attr` in the `events.redraw` event. You need to remember that a bar chart is an inverted column chart and where you have an x-axis there will be a y-axis.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        let chart = this,
          series = chart.series[0],
          title = this.title,
          point = series.points[0];
                    
        title.attr({
          x: chart.plotTop + point.x,
          y: chart.plotLeft + point.y 
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ud45prLg/